# AngularJS Directive which can compile another directive with access to parent controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

First here is my problem in a short pseudo code:

```
<book-ui>
    <icon> <!-- can access controller -->
    <icon-static> <!-- compiled and can not access controller -->
    <icon-animated><!-- compiled can not access controller -->
</book-ui>
```

And here is my explanation:

1. I have one parent directive `<bookd-ui>` and it has a controller
2. I have one child directive `<icon>` which should compile other directives depending on data passed to it via data attribute `<icon data="someData"></icon>`
3. Two other directives `<icon-static>` & `<icon-animated>` should be able to access `<book-ui>` controler (they are childs of `<book-ui>`)

Here is my example, where `<icon>` directive successfully compiles two other directives depending on some condition, and `<icon>` directive can access `<book-ui>` controller.

http://jsfiddle.net/poul_kg/Q5uHV/6/

the problem statrs when I add `require: '^bookUi'` to `<icon-static>` or to `<icon-animated>` directives (which are compiled directives). I don't have any errors when I add `require: '^bookUi'` to `<icon>` directive.

Why I do this. I want to add icons to book, all icons has the same data structute but behave completely differently depending on it's type, so I thought it will be good to separate them into two different directives. And in the template it is easier for me to use:

`<icon ng-repeat="icon in book.pages[currentPage].icons" data="book.pages[currentPage].icons[$index]"></icon>`

OR should I use some kind of `| filter:` expression here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In actual implementation you don't need `icon` directive.

You can use filter like `filter: {type_id: 1}` and your directive structure will look like

```
<book-ui>
    <icon-static data="el" ng-repeat="el in elements | filter: {type_id: 1}"></icon-static>
    <icon-animated data="el" ng-repeat="el in elements | filter: {type_id: 2}"></icon-animated>
</book-ui>
```

Also you can require parent directive `require: '^bookUi'`

Check the updated <kbd>[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Xjq9g/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I created my own custom filter because I need to test if type_id is element of set [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].